# ZigZag array implementation

Tags: java, array, sorting

I have implemented a zigzag array which will sort smaller greater smaller and goes on...

For example :

3 7 4 8 2 6 1 is a valid ordering.

The relationship between numbers is

3 < 7 > 4 < 8 > 2 < 6 > 1

```
3 smaller than 7
7 greater than 4
4 smaller than 8
8 greater than and so on
```

the ordering always has to be "smaller than" then "greater than" then "smaller than"...

Are there any other suggestions for improving the solution?

Thanks.

```
package main.algorithms;

public class ZigZag {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {4,3,7,8,6,2,1};
        zigZag(array);
        for (int i: array){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    // Time O(n)
    // Space O(1)
    private static int[] zigZag(int[] array) {

        int status = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < array.length-1){
            if(status ==0) {
                if (array[counter] > array[counter + 1]) {
                    int temp = array[counter + 1];
                    array[counter + 1] = array[counter];
                    array[counter] = temp;
                }
                status = 1;
            } else {
                if (array[counter] < array[counter + 1]) {
                    int temp = array[counter + 1];
                    array[counter + 1] = array[counter];
                    array[counter] = temp;
                }
                status = 0;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: @superb rain I just added extra explanation.

Answer (score 5):

- Instead of that `while`-loop, I'd use a `for`-loop and use the common loop/index variable `i`.
- Instead of a separate `status` variable, I'd simply use `i % 2`.
- I'd deduplicate the two cases.
- Putting the current two array elements into variables avoids duplicating the longer `array[i]` and `array[i + 1]` and simplifies the swap.
- As Joop Eggen points out, it's probably better to not modify the array in-place *and* return it. (Unless you have a good reason to, which it seems you don't, as your own calling code ignores the returned value.)

Code:

```
    private static void zigZag(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            int a = array[i], b = array[i + 1];
            if (i % 2 == 0 ? a > b : a < b) {
                array[i] = b;
                array[i + 1] = a;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very nice. It would be perfect when advising to use a void result, as the passed array is modified in-situ. Also a proof with pre and post conditions would be feasible, but that would ruin the compactness of your code.

Comment: @JoopEggen Right, added that (rephrased a bit).